# Time Series: ACF and PACF plot, how to tell what's the best model by looking at the plot?

Tags: time-series, self-study, mathematical-statistics, acf-pacf

The question ask me "The equation of the model you think is most appropriate, given the plots. Justify your choice of model. " the ACF plot looks like cut off after the first lag. And I'm not too sure about the PACF plot, it is showing decay or something else? and which model would be the best model? AR?MA?ARMA?
Thanks

[image: PACF plot]

[image: ACF plot]

Comment: Please add the `[self-study]` tag & read its 
[wiki](https://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info).

Comment: Hint: for the Box-Jenkins approach, what is important is *significant* peaks in the (P)ACF plots. Which peaks are significant in your case?